# Terraform AWS provider : Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use terraform as start to automate infrastructure provisioning. I already have VPC, subnets defined.  I could not solve this problem i have gone through similar questions posted on stack overflow to check the AMI's is available in region or check the VPC tenancy. Unfortunately these solution are not working for me.  Here is my simple configuration main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "test-instance1" {
  ami               = "ami-07dc734dc14746eab"
  ebs_optimized     = true
  instance_type     = "t2.micro"

  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = 260
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name           = "/dev/sda1"
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_size           = 260
    volume_type           = "gp2"
  }
}
```

Here is the complete output of terraform apply.

```
Master $ terraform apply

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.test-instance1 will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "test-instance1" {
      + ami                          = "ami-07dc734dc14746eab"
      + arn                          = (known after apply)
      + associate_public_ip_address  = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone            = (known after apply)
      + cpu_core_count               = (known after apply)
      + cpu_threads_per_core         = (known after apply)
      + ebs_optimized                = true
      + get_password_data            = false
      + host_id                      = (known after apply)
      + id                           = (known after apply)
      + instance_state               = (known after apply)
      + instance_type                = "t2.micro"
      + ipv6_address_count           = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_addresses               = (known after apply)
      + key_name                     = (known after apply)
      + network_interface_id         = (known after apply)
      + outpost_arn                  = (known after apply)
      + password_data                = (known after apply)
      + placement_group              = (known after apply)
      + primary_network_interface_id = (known after apply)
      + private_dns                  = (known after apply)
      + private_ip                   = (known after apply)
      + public_dns                   = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                    = (known after apply)
      + security_groups              = (known after apply)
      + source_dest_check            = true
      + subnet_id                    = (known after apply)
      + tenancy                      = (known after apply)
      + volume_tags                  = (known after apply)
      + vpc_security_group_ids       = (known after apply)

      + ebs_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = "/dev/sda1"
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 260
          + volume_type           = "gp2"
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      + metadata_options {
          + http_endpoint               = (known after apply)
          + http_put_response_hop_limit = (known after apply)
          + http_tokens                 = (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      + root_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 260
          + volume_type           = "gp2"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_instance.test-instance1: Creating...

Error: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
    status code: 400, request id: 1db1f3f0-88c5-4d71-bf9d-43f3a987b5c5

  on main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_instance" "test-instance1":
   5: resource "aws_instance" "test-instance1" {


Master $
```

I also enabled logs and set it to TRACE.  Here is the complete debug.

```
2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] aws_instance.test-instance1: applying the planned Create change
2020/05/11 22:48:38 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: ApplyResourceChange
2020-05-11T22:48:38.524+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "ephemeral_block_device" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.525+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "metadata_options" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.525+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "security_groups" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.525+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "network_interface" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.525+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "network_interface" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.525+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "vpc_security_group_ids" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.525+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "volume_tags" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.540+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] setting computed for "ipv6_addresses" from ComputedKeys
2020-05-11T22:48:38.547+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] Describing AMI "ami-07dc734dc14746eab" to get root block device name
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:38 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request ec2/DescribeImages Details:
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: ---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: POST / HTTP/1.1
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Host: ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.30.21 (go1.13.7; darwin; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.12.24 (+https://www.terraform.io)
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Content-Length: 72
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: X-Amz-Date: 20200511T171838Z
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Action=DescribeImages&ImageId.1=ami-07dc734dc14746eab&Version=2016-11-15
2020-05-11T22:48:38.553+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2020-05-11T22:48:39.761+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:39 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response ec2/DescribeImages Details:
2020-05-11T22:48:39.761+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2020-05-11T22:48:39.761+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Connection: close
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Date: Mon, 11 May 2020 17:18:39 GMT
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Server: AmazonEC2
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Vary: accept-encoding
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: X-Amzn-Requestid: 87d3ddcf-aacd-43fe-a7c2-3efb44d6d76b
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:39 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: <DescribeImagesResponse xmlns="http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2016-11-15/">
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     <requestId>87d3ddcf-aacd-43fe-a7c2-3efb44d6d76b</requestId>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     <imagesSet>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         <item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <imageId>ami-07dc734dc14746eab</imageId>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <imageLocation>099720109477/ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20190212.1</imageLocation>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <imageState>available</imageState>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <imageOwnerId>099720109477</imageOwnerId>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <creationDate>2019-02-13T12:48:49.000Z</creationDate>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <isPublic>true</isPublic>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <architecture>x86_64</architecture>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <imageType>machine</imageType>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <sriovNetSupport>simple</sriovNetSupport>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <name>ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20190212.1</name>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <description>Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS, amd64 bionic image build on 2019-02-12</description>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <rootDeviceType>ebs</rootDeviceType>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <rootDeviceName>/dev/sda1</rootDeviceName>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <blockDeviceMapping>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                 <item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                     <deviceName>/dev/sda1</deviceName>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                     <ebs>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                         <snapshotId>snap-0160fe9487706c145</snapshotId>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                         <volumeSize>8</volumeSize>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                         <deleteOnTermination>true</deleteOnTermination>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                         <volumeType>gp2</volumeType>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                         <encrypted>false</encrypted>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                     </ebs>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                 </item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                 <item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                     <deviceName>/dev/sdb</deviceName>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                     <virtualName>ephemeral0</virtualName>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.762+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                 </item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                 <item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                     <deviceName>/dev/sdc</deviceName>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                     <virtualName>ephemeral1</virtualName>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:                 </item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             </blockDeviceMapping>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <virtualizationType>hvm</virtualizationType>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <hypervisor>xen</hypervisor>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <enaSupport>true</enaSupport>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <platformDetails>Linux/UNIX</platformDetails>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:             <usageOperation>RunInstances</usageOperation>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         </item>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     </imagesSet>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.763+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: </DescribeImagesResponse>
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:39 [DEBUG] Run configuration: {
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   BlockDeviceMappings: [{
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:       DeviceName: "/dev/sda1",
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:       Ebs: {
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         DeleteOnTermination: true,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         VolumeSize: 260,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         VolumeType: "gp2"
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:       }
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     },{
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:       DeviceName: "/dev/sda1",
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:       Ebs: {
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         DeleteOnTermination: true,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         VolumeSize: 260,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:         VolumeType: "gp2"
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:       }
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     }],
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   DisableApiTermination: false,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   EbsOptimized: true,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   HibernationOptions: {
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     Configured: false
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   },
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   IamInstanceProfile: {
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     Name: ""
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   },
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   ImageId: "ami-07dc734dc14746eab",
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   InstanceType: "t2.micro",
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   MaxCount: 1,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   MinCount: 1,
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   Monitoring: {
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     Enabled: false
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   },
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   Placement: {
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     AvailabilityZone: "",
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:     GroupName: ""
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:   }
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: }
2020-05-11T22:48:39.782+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:39 [DEBUG] Waiting for state to become: [success]
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:39 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request ec2/RunInstances Details:
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: ---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: POST / HTTP/1.1
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Host: ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.30.21 (go1.13.7; darwin; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.12.24 (+https://www.terraform.io)
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Content-Length: 645
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: X-Amz-Date: 20200511T171839Z
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Action=RunInstances&BlockDeviceMapping.1.DeviceName=%2Fdev%2Fsda1&BlockDeviceMapping.1.Ebs.DeleteOnTermination=true&BlockDeviceMapping.1.Ebs.VolumeSize=260&BlockDeviceMapping.1.Ebs.VolumeType=gp2&BlockDeviceMapping.2.DeviceName=%2Fdev%2Fsda1&BlockDeviceMapping.2.Ebs.DeleteOnTermination=true&BlockDeviceMapping.2.Ebs.VolumeSize=260&BlockDeviceMapping.2.Ebs.VolumeType=gp2&DisableApiTermination=false&EbsOptimized=true&HibernationOptions.Configured=false&IamInstanceProfile.Name=&ImageId=ami-07dc734dc14746eab&InstanceType=t2.micro&MaxCount=1&MinCount=1&Monitoring.Enabled=false&Placement.AvailabilityZone=&Placement.GroupName=&Version=2016-11-15
2020-05-11T22:48:39.790+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2020/05/11 22:48:40 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
2020/05/11 22:48:40 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "aws_instance.test-instance1"
2020/05/11 22:48:40 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider.aws (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.test-instance1"
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:41 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response ec2/RunInstances Details:
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Connection: close
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Date: Mon, 11 May 2020 17:18:41 GMT
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: Server: AmazonEC2
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: -----------------------------------------------------
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:41 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: <Response><Errors><Error><Code>Unsupported</Code><Message>The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>1db1f3f0-88c5-4d71-bf9d-43f3a987b5c5</RequestID></Response>
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4: 2020/05/11 22:48:41 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response ec2/RunInstances failed, attempt 0/25, error Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
2020-05-11T22:48:41.622+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.61.0_x4:  status code: 400, request id: 1db1f3f0-88c5-4d71-bf9d-43f3a987b5c5
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [DEBUG] aws_instance.test-instance1: apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error pointer rather than returning it: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
    status code: 400, request id: 1db1f3f0-88c5-4d71-bf9d-43f3a987b5c5
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalMaybeTainted
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] EvalMaybeTainted: aws_instance.test-instance1 encountered an error during creation, so it is now marked as tainted
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: removing state object for aws_instance.test-instance1
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyProvisioners
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] EvalApplyProvisioners: aws_instance.test-instance1 has no state, so skipping provisioners
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalMaybeTainted
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] EvalMaybeTainted: aws_instance.test-instance1 encountered an error during creation, so it is now marked as tainted
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: removing state object for aws_instance.test-instance1
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteDiff
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
    status code: 400, request id: 1db1f3f0-88c5-4d71-bf9d-43f3a987b5c5
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
    status code: 400, request id: 1db1f3f0-88c5-4d71-bf9d-43f3a987b5c5
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] [walkApply] Exiting eval tree: aws_instance.test-instance1
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] vertex "aws_instance.test-instance1": visit complete
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" errored, so skipping
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider.aws (close)" errored, so skipping
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: not making a backup, because the new snapshot is identical to the old
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: no state changes since last snapshot
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: writing snapshot at terraform.tfstate
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: removing lock metadata file .terraform.tfstate.lock.info
2020/05/11 22:48:41 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: unlocking terraform.tfstate using fcntl flock
2020-05-11T22:48:41.683+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `t2` type instances do not support EBS Optimized volumes per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html#ebs-optimization-support. Try removing `ebs_optimized` or setting it to `false`.

Comment: Or just use t3 to get ebs_optimization and better performance for lower cost

Comment: It worked.  I changed the eps_optimized to false and it worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

instance_type     = "t2.micro"

change to

instance_type     = "t3.micro"

is OK for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).